# Удалится ли плагин если удалю его из вебпака и ещё раз сделаю install react

Tags: reactjs, webpack

1)Я могу чтобы удалить плагин сделать такую команду `npm uninstall <package_name>`
2)Если я удалю пакет из package.json в ручную, и переустановлю все модулю у меня пакет тоже удалится?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Для этого вам необходимо удалить его из package.json, удалить папку node_modules и потом выполнить npm install

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, удалится. Хотя, рекомендуется, конечно, так не делать, и удалять через `npm uninstall` (или какой Вы там пакетный менеджер используете).